# How to interact with Fuseki using Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, fuseki

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://semanticwebrecipes.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/fuseki-it-really-is-that-easy/) to insert a new resource into `Fuseki`'s dataset, but I'm getting this error:

> the method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

This is the code:

```
import java.util.UUID;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateProcessor;

/**
 * Example connection to Fuseki. For this to work, you need to start a local
 * Fuseki server like this: ./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
 */
public class FusekiTest {
    /** A template for creating a nice SPARUL query */
    private static final String UPDATE_TEMPLATE = 
            "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>"
            + "INSERT DATA"
            + "{ <http://example/%s>    dc:title    \"A new book\" ;"
            + "                         dc:creator  \"A.N.Other\" ." + "}   ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Add a new book to the collection
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(String.format("Adding %s", id));
        UpdateProcessor upp = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(
                UpdateFactory.create(String.format(UPDATE_TEMPLATE, id)), 
                "http://localhost:3030/ds/update");
        upp.execute();
    }

}
```

[image]

How can I fix that error?

Comment: `import com.hp.hpl` - that's an old version of Jena.

Comment: The second argument to `String.format` is varargs. The error suggests some kind of java problem.

Comment: @AndyS is right. It looks like you're using a quite old version in your Eclipse setup. to be more precise, varargs have been introduced in Java 5 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), thus, you're using probably Java 4! this is ancient, please fix this in your project specific compiler settings of Eclipse.

Comment: @AKSW I've changed my Java version to 1.6 but I'm still getting that error on `String.format`... is there anything else that I need to change?

Comment: @AndyS could you please help me with that  error on `String.format`? All I really want is to get the code working and be able to upload some RDF data to Fuseki server... Thank you!

Comment: I really need help solving this issue because I'm new to Java...

Comment: Fixed it! I didn't change the java version in the right place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is common when the java project version is 1.4.

It's a common problem that the project Java version is set to 1.4 or 1.6 by default in the template by the IDE. You should make sure that you have the correct Java version set on your project.

### How to change your Java version

**Eclipse:**

Right click project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> select JRE System Library click Edit and select JDK or JRE after then click Java Compiler and select Compiler compliance level to 1.8

**IntelliJ**

Menu -> File -> Project structure -> project SDK

**Netbeans**

*This assumes that you installed JDK 1.6 and NetBeans knows about this.*

- Right-click on the Project and select Properties.
- Under Library, select Java Platform JDK 1.8.
- Select Source/Binary Format JDK8 in the Source category.

The JDK 1.8 must already have been supplied to NetBeans. To do that you got to menu -> Tools-> Java Platform Manager.